# pythonic string syntax corrector

Tags: python

I wrote a script to catch and correct commands before they are read by a parser. The parser requires equal, not equal, greater, etc, entries to be separated by commas, such as:

'test(a>=b)' is wrong
'test(a,>=,b)' is correct

The script i wrote works fine, but i would love to know if there's a more efficient way to do this.

Here's my script:

```
# Correction routine
def corrector(exp):
    def rep(exp,a,b):
        foo = ''
        while(True):
            foo = exp.replace(a,b)
            if foo == exp:
                return exp
            exp = foo

    # Replace all instances with a unique identifier. Do it in a specific order
    # so for example we catch an instance of '>=' before we get to '='
    items = ['>=','<=','!=','==','>','<','=']
    for i in range(len(items)):
        exp = rep(exp,items[i],'###%s###'%i)

    # Re-add items with commas
    for i in range(len(items)):
        exp = exp.replace('###%s###'%i,',%s,'%items[i])

    # Remove accidental double commas we may have added
    return exp.replace(',,',',')


print corrector('wrong_syntax(b>=c) correct_syntax(b,>=,c)')
// RESULT: wrong_syntax(b,>=,c) correct_syntax(b,>=,c)
```

thanks!

Comment: I think you probably want to use a regular expression.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is where you want to post this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/regex.html -- Read especially the .sub() method

Comment: @IanAuld thanks, will do so in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, one approach would be to use a regular expression.  The following regex matches any of your operators when they are not surrounded by commas, and replaces them with the same string with the commas inserted:

```
inputstring = 'wrong_syntax(b>=c) correct_syntax(b,>=,c)'
regex = r"([^,])(>=|<=|!=|==|>|<|=)([^,])"
replace = r"\1,\2,\3"

result = re.sub(regex, replace, inputstring)

print(result)
```

Simple regexes are relatively easy, but they can get complicated quickly.  Check out the docs for more info:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: i'll take this as my answer. I don't know why i never think of regex for anything else than string matching. Now i have good reason to get comfortable with it for substitution :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex that will do what you asked:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'''

    (?<!,)                  # Negative lookbehind
    (!=|[><=]=?)
    (?!,)                   # Negative lookahead

''', re.VERBOSE)
print regex.sub(r',\1,', 'wrong_expression(b>=c) or right_expression(b,>=,c)')
```

outputs

```
wrong_expression(b,>=,c) or right_expression(b,>=,c)
```

Comment: thanks! I need to not shy away from regex in the future and get comfortable with it.